# How to fetch records from three models having one to one associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, one-to-one

I am having three model. They are as defined below:

```
#Checkout Model
class Checkout < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery_visitor
end

#GalleryVisitor Model
class GalleryVisitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_one :checkout
end

#Gallery Model
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :gallery_visitors, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I am willing to fetch all the gallery on the basis of the checkout model.
How can i get using includes()?
Can anyone help me out? Thank you in advace.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can try this way:

```
Gallery.includes({gallery_visitors: [:checkout]}).where(checkouts: {condition})
```

Comment: I think he needs gallery on basis of checkout

Comment: @Deepak your query return `checkout` not galleries. in above query you can put condition on checkout model it will return you gallaries

Comment: @vishal thanks a lot. It worked like a miracle to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can even make this query **`shorter`** and **`quicker`** by adding an association from,

**`Gallery to Checkout through Gallery Visitors`** in a **more rails** way.

Add the line `has_one :checkout,through: :gallery_visitors` to Gallery model,

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :gallery_visitors, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :checkout,through: :gallery_visitors
end
```

reload the console, and try this query

`Gallery.includes(:checkout).where(checkout: {condition})`

`Eg: Gallery.includes(:checkout).where(checkout: {id: 1})`

This makes a direct relation-ship and makes the query quicker.